# How to customize OutputCache key in MVC, c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I'm working with MVC 5 and Razor engine.
I have a controller's action as the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[OutputCache(Duration = 120, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, VaryByParam = "*")]
public PartialViewResult Index(DevicesAjaxViewModel viewModel)
{ ... }
```

As you can see the action parameter is a class, when ever I'm using `OutputCache` nothing cached and action runs in each request. I thing it's because of cache key.
So how can I customize `OutputCache`? Is it possible?

Comment: Did you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193383/outputcache-varying-by-a-complex-object-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have caching because VaryByParam is set to everything - *. Usually that option is used to specify part of the input parameters (your viewModel) of the controller action.